# my pip install in python shell is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, package

so i am a beginner python programmer when i was trying to do a chatbot as a training but the problem is when i wrote pip install chatterbot in the python shell they give me an syntax error and when i searched on the net and on YOUTUBE .all the videos have the same solution that's  going to the environnement variables then going to path and add some files address but i had the files address of python but it still not working . i am working in windows 10 and python 3.9 (64bit)this is the photo of the problem and thanks for answering me.[the syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIwpX.jpg)

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining the problem, what you tried, what you're using, and the exact outcome. Good job asking a good question!

Comment: thank you i was just typing all what i know about my problem .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use pip installs in terminals. So on PyCharm use the terminal tab on the bottom of the main window.

Comment: thanks i use visual studio code but the problem is solved i as trying to install the package in python shell

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to run a pip command in the *Python interpreter*, which only understands Python code.

If you're on Windows, open **Command Prompt** (cmd) and run your pip command from there.

Comment: thank you so much i had this problem a month ago and i was very mad so i didn't talk about python anymore so one of my friends told me about stack overflow .  thanks another time it's now downloading